# How to map a xml file to a new xml file based on a xsd in python?

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I have 2 xsd files (A.xsd and B.xsd). A.xsd includes 100 elements, and B.xsd includes 20 elements. The 20 elements in B.xsd are also included in A.xsd.

Also, I have a xml file whose schema is corresponding to A.xsd.

I would like to map the 100 elements in the xml to a new xml file whose schema is following the B.xsd.

Is there any easy way to deal with this in python? Thank you so much!

A.xsd example

```
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="address1" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="address2" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
```

B.xsd example

```
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
```

xml example

```
<name>UNIONTOWN, PA</name>
<address1>testtesttest</address1>
<address2>testtesttest Commons</address2>
<city>Uniontown</city>
```

2nd xml example (finally required)

```
<name>UNIONTOWN, PA</name>
<city>Uniontown</city>
```

Comment: Your question implies that `B.xsd` is a subset of `A.xsd`. It is unlikely that you can successfully validate your XML file with only a subset of its XSD.

Comment: But to be sure, a [mcve] is needed. This should be easy, because your XSDs seem to be small. So `A.xsd`, `B.xsd` and a sample XML file will be required to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're doing a transformation that drops the elements that aren't defined in B.xsd? Well, if the two schemas are sufficiently straightforward, you could do an XSLT transformation that takes these two schemas as input, builds a list of the elements that are declared in A but not in B, and outputs this list in the form of an XSLT stylesheet that drops the relevant elements:

```
<xsl:template match="address1|address2"/>
```

plus an identity template rule to copy everything else unchanged.

Of course there's no guarantee that the output of this transformation will actually be valid against B.xsd - that depends on the exact nature of the differences.